# JSF 2 panelGrid column formatting - uniform alignment

Tags: css, jsf, facelets

I have a multi column form that I need to display and I used the JSF panelGrid component like this. each panelgrid is within a primefaces p:panel element

```
<h:panelGrid columns="6" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" style="width: 100%"  columnClasses="column1">
```

my column1 in CSS is:

```
.column1 {
width: 14%;
```

}

It renders on screen like image below. Notice the columns within the panels are not aligned and it looks haphazard. How can I align the form elements/labels in a uniform manner and also get rid of the spaces and padding to make the form layout more compact.

[image: panelGrid layout]

Thanks in Advance BaluSC if you answer! You really are the king of JSF:-)

Comment: Did you solve this problem? Run into the same.

Comment: I did not:-(. re-designed the layout by reducing padding and text

Answer (score 1):

I also have a multi-column form using JSF PanelGrid.

```
<h:panelGrid id="panelGrid" columns="4" cellpadding="3"
        columnClasses="colLeft,colRight,colLeft,colRight">
        <p:outputLabel for="username" value="Username" />
        <p:inputText id="username" value="#{myBean.user.username}"
            required="true" />

        <p:outputLabel for="fullName" value="Full Name" />
        <p:inputText id="fullName" value="#{myBean.user.fullName}"
            required="true" />

        <p:outputLabel for="password" value="Password" />
        <p:password id="password" value="#{myBean.user.password}"
            required="true" match="passConfirm" />

        <p:outputLabel for="passConfirm"
            value="Re-type Password" />
        <p:password id="passConfirm" value="#{myBean.user.password}"
            required="true" />
</h:panelGrid>
```

*Here is CSS.*

```
#panelGrid {
    width: 100%;
}

.colLeft {
    width: 15%;
}

.colRight {
    width: 35%;
}
```

*Here is output.*

[image]

Hope it works!